# How to set Security Preference on reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: security, recaptcha, preference

We have setting "Security Preference" option in reCAPTCHA v2. but there is no option for reCAPTCHA v3. Is it possible to set Security Preference on reCAPTCHA v3?

Need Security Preference option settings on reCAPTCHA v3.